# Почему нельзя сделать ссылку на память внутри условия?

Tags: rust

```
fn foo(mut a: &Vec<i32>){

    let mut c: Vec<i32>;

    if a[0] == 0 {
        c = vec![1; 3];
        a = &c;
    }
    println!("{:?}",a);
}

fn main(){
    let a:Vec<i32> = vec![0; 3];
    foo(&a);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
main.rs:9:14: 9:15 error: `c` does not live long enough
main.rs:9         a = &c;
                       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Вектор "с" будет уничтожен после выхода из условия "if a[0] == 0".
Именно на это компилятор и ругается.
Что-бы заменить данные вектора "а" данными вектора "с", можно попробовать такой код:

```
fn foo(a: &mut Vec<i32>){

    let mut c: Vec<i32>;

    if a[0] == 0 {
        c = vec![1; 3];
        //a = &c;
        a.clear();
        a.extend( c.into_iter() ); 
    }
    println!("{:?}",a);
}

fn main(){
    let mut a:Vec<i32> = vec![0; 3];
    foo(&mut a);
}
```

Comment: Это не то, что я имел ввиду. Когда я писал `foo(&a);`, я хотел скопировать ссылку на вектор, а не на переменную. В следствии этого я не понимал почему он ругается на изменение `a` внутри `foo`.
Свою ошибку я понял только после того, как [получил очевидное решение](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671076/why-cant-i-make-a-reference-to-memory-inside-if), но на мой взгляд оно костыльное. Я пролистал документацию еще несколько раз, но так и не увидел примера того, что я хочу.

Comment: Небольшое уточнение: время жизни `c` — вся функция, а не только блок `if`. Потому что объявлена она раньше блока `if`, в начале функции через оператор `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически вы пытаетесь передать ссылку на локальную переменную `c` наружу, но эта переменная размещена на стеке и будет уничтожена в конце функции `foo()`, так что ссылка на неё `&c` станет невалидной (на что и ругается компилятор).

И мне не совсем понятно, зачем вы это хотите сделать? Скорее всего в расте есть более правильный способ сделать то же самое.